# Pycharm бесконечно думает

Tags: python, input, pycharm

Коротко по существу:
только начинаю разбираться с python, и пытаюсь решить тривиальную задачу: чтение массива из семи чисел из текстового файла

```
file_descriptor = open(r'seven.txt')
sev = file_descriptor.read()
file_descriptor.close()
sev = list(map(int, input(sev).split()))
print(sev)
```

Казалось бы, просто до слёз, однако pycharm на команде input уходит в бесконечную задумчивость. В аппаратной части точно проблем нет. Подскажите, в чем причина? Неужели январские праздники?

Comment: Так вы не вводите ничего в консоль, наверное.

Comment: input имеется в виду функция, которая переводит переменную, представляющую собой строку из чисел, разделенных пробелами в массив строк (сплит для ликвидации пробелов, лист-мап для перевода из строк в числа)

Comment: Вы, похоже, забыли как работает input. Он получает данные _из консоли_, а вы туда ничего не вводите. Он просто ждет, когда вы что-то (хотя непонятно, что?) введете.

Comment: Спасибо за активность, сам сперва не догадался, в чем смысл. Да, нужно было просто к переменной sev напрямую применять .split()
Я не волшебник, я только учусь)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы просто забыли, как работает `input()`. Когда вы передаете ему что-то в качестве аргумента, он выводит это "что-то" в консоль как объяснение происходящему и ждет что вы ответите. Правильный код, вероятно, такой:

```
with open(r'seven.txt') as file_descriptor:
    sev = file_descriptor.read()
    file_descriptor.close()
sev = [int(i) for i in sev.split()]
print(sev)
```

Comment: Непонятно только, зачем вы продвинутый вариант с `map` поменяли на списковое сокращение, ну да ладно )

Comment: @CrazyElf, я просто лист-мап не очень люблю, запутаться с ним очень просто.

Comment: А мне формат записи спискового сокращения кажется избыточным. Два раза пишется переменная `i`, которую в функциональной записи можно вообще не писать, скобки от вызова `int`. Не люблю повторения и излишества в коде. )  Но про понятность согласен, списковое сокращение более явное и понятное.